# Translating proof from Nat to Rat

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I'm trying to use a CoQ/SSReflect proof using `nat` to prove a very similar statement in `rat`. The current proof status, within an `Open Scope ring_scope`, is

```
  (price bs i - price bs' i <= tnth bs i * ('ctr_ (sOi i) - 'ctr_ (sOi i')))%N
  → (price bs i)%:~R - (price bs' i)%:~R <=
    (value_per_click i)%:~R * (('ctr_ (sOi i))%:~R - ('ctr_ (sOi i'))%:~R)
```

and, using `Set Printing All`, it shows as

```
 forall
    _ : is_true
          (leq (subn (price bs i) (price bs' i))
             (muln (@nat_of_ord p (@tnth n bid bs i))
                (subn (@nat_of_ord q (@tnth k ctr cs (sOi i)))
                   (@nat_of_ord q (@tnth k ctr cs (sOi i')))))),
  is_true
    (@Order.le ring_display (Num.NumDomain.porderType rat_numDomainType)
       (@GRing.add rat_ZmodType
          (@intmul (GRing.Ring.zmodType rat_Ring) (GRing.one rat_Ring) (Posz (price bs i)))
          (@GRing.opp rat_ZmodType
             (@intmul (GRing.Ring.zmodType rat_Ring) (GRing.one rat_Ring) (Posz (price bs' i)))))
       (@GRing.mul rat_Ring
          (@intmul (GRing.Ring.zmodType rat_Ring) (GRing.one rat_Ring)
             (Posz (value_per_click i)))
          (@GRing.add (GRing.Ring.zmodType rat_Ring)
             (@intmul (GRing.Ring.zmodType rat_Ring) (GRing.one rat_Ring)
                (Posz (@nat_of_ord q (@tnth k ctr cs (sOi i)))))
             (@GRing.opp (GRing.Ring.zmodType rat_Ring)
                (@intmul (GRing.Ring.zmodType rat_Ring) (GRing.one rat_Ring)
                   (Posz (@nat_of_ord q (@tnth k ctr cs (sOi i')))))))))
```

I have been trying to use various `rewrite` such as `ler_nat`, `PoszM`, `intrM`, but with not much success. Could anyone provide me with some hints on how to proceed?

PS: I'm not able to provide a minimal working example, given I'm not exactly mastering what I'm doing here ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you might have noticed, going from `nat` to `rat` there are two embeddings: first from `nat` to `int`, then from `int` to `rat`. The latter is a ring morphism, you can thus use generic morphism theorems such as `rmorphM` and `rmorphB`, in your case you could start with `rewrite -!rmorphB -rmorphM ler_int.`

The former embedding (`Posz : nat ->  int`) however is not a ring morphism, you could still use `PoszM` indeed (`Posz` is multiplicative), but the major problem would be that `Posz (m - n) != Posz m - Posz n` in general (and the silent insertion of the coercion complicates matter here). So it would appear that you would need to postulate both `(price bs' i <= price bs i)%N` and `'ctr_ (sOi i') <= 'ctr_ (sOi i)`. However thanks to `leq_subLR` you can avoid the first hypothesis.

Here is a mock-up of your problem and a solution (it would have been nice to have the full context if you could not minimize). Assuming I reverse engineered the right types for `price _ _` (thereafter abbreviated with `p` and `p'`), `'ctr _ _` (thereafter abbreviated with `c` and `c'`) and `value_per_click _` (abbrev `v`):

```
Lemma test (p p' v c c' : nat) : (c' <= c)%N -> (p - p' <= v * (c - c'))%N ->
  p%:~R - p'%:~R <= v%:~R * (c%:~R - c'%:~R) :> rat.
Proof.
rewrite leq_subLR => le_c'c le_pp'_vMcc'. (* Removing the first subn. *)
rewrite -!rmorphB -rmorphM ler_int. (* Changing rat goal into int goal. *)
by rewrite ler_subl_addl subzn. (* Changing int goal into nat goal. *)
(* The rest of the proof was actually carried out using conversion. *)
Qed.
```

Comment: This is working like a charm: thanks, Cyril. I I assume the `rmorph*`rewrites infer that the morphism is the coercion function. I  guess a mistake was also my mind set to going from `nat` to `rat`, instead of the opposite.